# Why would a line that sets value of array A resets my value in array B?

Tags: java, arrays

So this is my class (UvicCourse.java):

```
public class UvicCourse {

//INSTANCE VARIABLES
private String dept = "";
private int num = 0;
private String title = "";

//CONSTRUCTORS
public UvicCourse(String dept, int num) {
    this.dept = dept;
    this.num = num; 
}

public UvicCourse(String dept, int num, String title) {
    this.dept = dept;
    this.num = num; 
    this.title = title;
}

public UvicCourse() {
    this.dept = "AAA";
    this.num = 100;
    this.title = "A course";    
}

//SETTER AND GETTER METHODS
public void setDept(String dept) {
    this.dept = dept;   
}

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDept() {
    return this.dept;   
}

public int getNum() {
    return this.num;    
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;  
}

//TOSTRING METHOD
public String toString() {
    return dept + " " + num + ": "+title;
}
}
```

Then this is my program.(UvicOrganizer)
I'm trying to sort a list.

```
public static void sortByNumber(UvicCourse[] arr){
    System.out.println("Before sorting: ");
    printArray(arr);

    UvicCourse[] newArr = new UvicCourse[arr.length];
    int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            if (arr[j].getNum() < small){
                small = arr[j].getNum();
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        newArr[i] = arr[minIndex];
        small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        arr[minIndex].setNum(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //I don't know why this line changes the value in my newArr.
    }

    System.out.println("After sorting: ");
    printArray(newArr);
}
```

This is what i get as result:

```
Before sorting:
PHYS 323:  Quantum Mechanics I
CSC 498:  Bioinformatics Project
ENGL 341:  Old English Literature
PHYS 342:  Computers in Science
CSC 110:  Fundamentals of Programming I
PHYS 102:  General Physics
MATH 100:  Calculus I
ENGL 135:  Academic Reading and Writing
CSC 225:  Algorithms and Data Structures I
MATH 211:  Matrix Algebra I

After sorting:
MATH 999:  Calculus I
PHYS 999:  General Physics
CSC 999:  Fundamentals of Programming I
ENGL 999:  Academic Reading and Writing
MATH 999:  Matrix Algebra I
CSC 999:  Algorithms and Data Structures I
PHYS 999:  Quantum Mechanics I
ENGL 999:  Old English Literature
PHYS 999:  Computers in Science
CSC 999:  Bioinformatics Project
```

Why it changes the course number to 999?
Didn't I assign it to a new array before i set the old one to 999?

Comment: because both arrays hold values of references to an object instance. Since you declare `newArr[i] = arr[minIndex];` you are basicly just copying this reference values into the other array, and changing the values of one array will effect the second array aswell, because you are working on the same object instances in both arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Your arrays hold references to `UvicCourse` instances.

When you write

```
newArr[i] = arr[minIndex];
```

The i'th element of both arrays refers to the same object, so modifying that object affects both arrays.

If you don't want that to happen, you have to create a copy of each `UvicCourse` instance before assigning it to `newArr[i]` (you can either use a copy constructor or `clone`).